# Issue: SwiftUI Button in Toolbar does not respond with empty array in a ForEach loop

Tags: swiftui-list

Issue: SwiftUI Button in Toolbar does not respond with empty array in a ForEach loop. (see attached code snippet)

The **viewModel.fetchAllContainer()** function in **OnAppear()** queries a DB and fills the **viewModel.fmContainers** array

When I start the app with an empty database, the plus.circle button in the toolbar does not respond. However, once a record is present in **viewModel.fmContainers**, the UI responds as expected.

```
....
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List {
                ForEach(viewModel.fmContainers, id: \.id) { fmContainer in
                    Button {
                        modal = .update_Container(fmContainer)
                    } label: {
                        FMContainerCellView(fmContainer: fmContainer)
                    }
                }
                .sheet(item: $modal) {
                    // Aufräumarbeiten z.B. nachladen
                    Task {
                        do {
                            try await viewModel.fetchAllContainer()
                        } catch {
                            print("ERROR: FMContainer not loaded")
                        }
                    }

                    
                } content: { modal in
                    switch modal {
                    case .add:
                        // new Container
                        FMContainerDetailView(viewModel: FMContainerDetailViewModel() )
                    case .update_Container(let fmContainer):
                        // update Container
                        FMContainerDetailView(viewModel: FMContainerDetailViewModel(isUpdating: true, fmContainer: fmContainer))
                    default:
                        Text("Error")
                    }
                }
            }
            .listStyle(PlainListStyle())
            .navigationTitle("Objektliste")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItem {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.circle")
                        .onTapGesture {
                            modal = .add
                        }
                }
            }
            .onAppear() {
                Task {
                    do {
                        try await viewModel.fetchAllContainer()
                     
                    } catch {
                        print("ERROR: FMContainer not loaded")
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO - Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to improve, edit and format your questions. 

Without a [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) it is impossible to help you troubleshoot.

Comment: I have an array that I'm rendering in a NavigationView with List and ForEach loop. I would like to add new entities to this array via a button using a separate "Create" dialog window. This button is represented by the toolbar option. This also works wonderfully as long as there is an entity in the array. If the array is empty (usually always at the beginning) I cannot call the "Create" dialog. Since the array is the result of a database query, it can also be empty.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In [link](https://docs.vapor.codes/fluent/relations/#nested-eager-load)) describes exactly what I was looking for. Thanks